# Launchd failure after calling SMJobBless

Tags: cocoa

I am working on an application that will update /etc/hosts. For this, I found that the preferred method of evaluating privileges is by installing a helper tool via SMJobBless. The following code sort of works:

```
    BOOL result = NO;

AuthorizationItem authItem      = { kSMRightBlessPrivilegedHelper, 0, NULL, 0 };
AuthorizationRights authRights  = { 1, &authItem };
AuthorizationFlags flags        =   kAuthorizationFlagDefaults              |
                                    kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed    |
                                    kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize          |
                                    kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

AuthorizationRef authRef = NULL;
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

OSStatus status = AuthorizationCreate(&authRights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags, &authRef);
if (status == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
    result = SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, (CFStringRef)@"com.fictitiousnonsense.MeddoHelper", authRef, &error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to authorize");
}

if (error != NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"I think it worked");
}
```

My helper tool, com.fictitiousnonsense.MeddoHelper is installed to /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.fictitiousnonsense.MeddoHelper and the plist file for it is installed to /Library/LaunchDaemons, all according to the documentation. The problem is that then this appears in my console:

```
9/24/12 11:04:41.237 PM launchdadd[9082]: Could not open /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.fictitiousnonsense.MeddoHelper (open() error 2: No such file or directory)
9/24/12 11:04:41.237 PM launchdadd[9082]: FAILURE: The path /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.fictitiousnonsense.MeddoHelper does not exist on-disk.
```

I can manually run the helper from the terminal and it works. Why won't launchd run it? I have run the SMJobBlessApp sample app that Apple provides and it works fine, my won't, and I can't find a different.

For reference, the entire code is here: https://github.com/varikin/meddo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dtruss` on the command line to trace launchd. It'll show you all the syscalls executed by launchd, and one of those should try to access your privileged helper. The trace should show which syscalls fails precisely that makes launchd think the helper is not there. I'm guessing that it's some sort of permission issue, btw.

Comment: If I manually run launchd, my installed helper is started successfully. It is only the launchd run from SMJobBless that fails. I don't have insight into how that works. *edit*: I think it might be a timing issue of the helper being copied over and launchd being run, but I can't confirm that.